# Hide a fixed footer?

Tags: javascript, css, footer, css-position

Hi I was wondering is there a way to hide a fixed footer with a button, so it can be closed by the user if they want to see more of the screen and vise versa. Is there a way to do this with css or will it require javascript?

cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="HideFooter()" />

function HideFooter()
{
    var display = document.getElementById("myFooter").style.display;
    if(display=="none")
        document.getElementById("myFooter").style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById("myFooter").style.display="none";
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){

    if($("#myFooter").is(":visible"))
        $("#myFooter").hide();
    else
        $("#myFooter").show();
});
```

**If you want some other nice effects**

```
$("#myFooter").fadeOut(500);
$("#myFooter").slideUp(500);
$("#myFooter").slideToggle(500); //Hide and Show
```

Another method, as **Bram Vanroy** Suggested:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){

    $("#myFooter").toggle();
});
```

Comment: You might want to make that a toggle.

Comment: @BramVanroy I updated my answer to allow hide/show in all cases.

Comment: You could just use `.toggle()` instead of the if-statement.:

`$("myFooter").toggle();`

Answer (score 3):

It will require `JavaScript`. Your button click event handler needs to change the `display` property of the footer to `none`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a javascript only version, with the button having and id of "button" and footer id of "footer". This method will allow you to show the footer again after hiding it, if the user wants to see it again.

```
   var button = document.getElementById('button');

    button.onclick = function() {
        var div = document.getElementById('footer');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
    $("#footer").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice tutsplus [video tutorial](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/slides-and-structure/?WT.mc_id=learnjquery) for exactly what you need. It's a simple bit of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to watch the video.